# Escaping Unicode characters in Ruby without getting extra double quotes

Tags: ruby, unicode, escaping

I'm trying to escape a string containing non-ASCII Unicode chars for use in JSON *and a logfile*, using Ruby 1.9.3pl194. The thing consuming the JSON can't handle non-ASCII so I need to produce an escaped version, however...

```
a = "Abc\u00eddef"
puts a
puts a.inspect
```

produces:

```
Abcídef
"Abc\u00EDdef"
```

Note that the second output includes unwanted double quotes, I don't want quotes as I want to write just the string `Abc\u00eddef` to a file; it's not just for use in a JSON string.

The same thing happens if I try and use `ActionSupport::JSON.decode(b)`

I know I can just do

```
puts a.inspect[1..-2]
```

but that's kind of ugly, surely there's a way of doing this without having to strip off quotes?

It's plain old Ruby so I don't have `.html_safe` that comes in rails (not sure whether that would work or not anyway).

Comment: Stripping non-ASCII characters can make the resulting text unreadable or turn it into non-sense. Do you need to keep its meaning? You could use HTML encoding, which turns all non-ASCII into something safe, but you can recover the values if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's how ActiveSupport tackles the problem](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L130):

```
def escape(string)
  string = string.encode(::Encoding::UTF_8, :undef => :replace).force_encoding(::Encoding::BINARY)
  json = string.
    gsub(escape_regex) { |s| ESCAPED_CHARS[s] }.
    gsub(/([\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|
           [\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|
           [\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3})+/nx) { |s|
    s.unpack("U*").pack("n*").unpack("H*")[0].gsub(/.{4}/n, '\\\\u\&')
  }
  json = %("#{json}")
  json.force_encoding(::Encoding::UTF_8)
  json
end
```

As you can see it's not trivial! Therefore the best solution might be to use `ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(whatever)` and strip the quotes (if you really must).